# how to trigger a button when a certain key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, button

```
          ...
          <div className="wrap">
          <div id="tiles" className="columns">
          <div id="ti">
       <button id ="Q" className='drum-pad'>Q</button>
       <button className='drum-pad'>W</button>
       <button className='drum-pad'>A</button>
       <button className='drum-pad'>S</button>
       <button className='drum-pad'>D</button>
       <button className='drum-pad'>S</button>
       <button className='drum-pad'>Z</button>
       <button className='drum-pad'>X</button>
       <button className='drum-pad'>C</button>

       </div>
       </div>
         ...
```

Hello i would like to triger the first button when the Q key is pressed and so on with W A S D etc, but i cant finc a way to do that can you help me please?

Comment: Why do you need to trigger the button at all? You could have the keyboard event call the same function as the button

Answer (score 1):

What you asking for is trigger a button when you press Q key. You could directly trigger a function when Q pressed instead of triggering a button but here is the code :

```js
var qkey = document.getElementById("Q"); //get the button element

function triggerQ(){                     //trigger a click on the button
qkey.click();
}

function log(){
console.log("Q pressed");                //log a message on console
}

window.addEventListener('keydown',function(event) { //check if Q pressed
    if (event.key == "q"){
        triggerQ();
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="Q" value="Q" onclick="log()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have an handler for the keydown event that when triggered will loop through all the available `.drum-pad` elements and compare the typed character against each one of them clicking which one has its innerText matching the pressed key:

```js
/**
 * This part only adds a click event handler to all the .drum-pad
 * that will print out on console which pad was just clicked
 * (the event gets fired both when the button is actually clicked with mouse
 * ..and when the corresponding character gets pressed)
 */
//when the page is loaded 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
  //for each element having the drum-pad class
  document.querySelectorAll('.drum-pad').forEach((o, i)=>{
    //adds the handler for the click event for the current element in the loop
    o.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
      //print out on console which pad triggered the click event
      console.log(`Clicked Pad: ${event.target.innerText}`);
    });  
  });
});

//when the event keydown gets fired on window (the page in the browser)
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  //get all the elements having the drum-pad class
  const pads = document.querySelectorAll('.drum-pad');
  //for each on of them
  for(let pad of pads){
    //get the innerText of the current element in the loop
    const keypad = pad.innerText;       
    //if the pressed key is equal to the current element in the loop
    if (event.key.toLowerCase() == keypad.toLowerCase()){
      //toggle the active status on the current button
      pad.classList.toggle('active');
      //fire the click event on the element
      pad.click();
      //wait 100ms and then toggle again the active status for the current button
      setTimeout( ()=>{pad.classList.toggle('active')}, 100);
      //exit the event handler
      return;
    }
  }    
})
```

```css
button:active, button.active {
  box-shadow: box-shadow: 7px 6px 28px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transform: translateY(4px);      
}
```

```html
<button class='drum-pad'>Q</button>
<button class='drum-pad'>W</button>
<button class='drum-pad'>A</button>
<button class='drum-pad'>S</button>
<button class='drum-pad'>D</button>
<button class='drum-pad'>S</button>
<button class='drum-pad'>Z</button>
<button class='drum-pad'>X</button>
<button class='drum-pad'>C</button>
```

Comment: I just have to copy this code above my previous code?

Comment: Yes place it between `<script> </script>` balise or [link a js file](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp)

Comment: I hoped you had a better understanding of the basics. The point is that your html is not strictly valid (as long as you just specified javascript among the questions tags and you didnt specify react for example) so it wouldn't work in a plain html/css/js playfield. The demo is consistent as it's shown. `className` should be `class` in vanilla html. If you want to integrate that solution in your code, make sure your html is compatible (elements having the drum-pad class). I also added a new detail to deal with the active state when the click is simulated.

Comment: when I put your code it tells me : Line 12:3:  'o' is not defined

Comment: It is not working but thank you thought

Comment: the `o` you are talking about it's surely the variable used in the forEach loop at the beginning. I only added now that block to run only when the page is loaded.. but undefined it's not an expected outcome so I may suspect you didn't correctly include the whole script. Just try again to include the whole script part of my demo inside a `<script></script>` in your page that has also a list of elements with class `drum-pad` as showed. If you can't make it work by then I really don't know what to say but you are doing something weird.